# Using blank? or present? in model-scopes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my model, I have several scopes defined such as:

```
scope :myScope1, where('myField IS NULL')
```

This works, but I don't need to check for 'Null' - I need to check for '.blank?' - because there are cases of non-nulls which are 'blank' in the DB, which I need to include.  I can use '.blank?' in my class-defs (and do - and they work there), but I cannot use this in this current context.

I have not been able to find a syntax (of the non-depreciated variety) which will work for this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`scope :myScope1, where("myField IS NULL or CAST(myField as text) = ''")`

It's not that simple as `blank?`, but I can't see a simple enough solution.

Comment: Thanks for the 'cast' tip - that might do the trick.  It seems bizarre that one cannot simply test a field with the standard methods. If no one has a better idea, I'll mark yours as the solution.